# How should I proceed to solve the below mentioned non-convex optimisation problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, random-matrices, non-convex-optimization

I am a newbie in the optimization domain. I am trying to solve a real-life problem. Where I have a set of equations to solve, with multiple variables.

The main equation looks like
$x1[(w1*w7)+(w4*w8)]+x2[(w2*w7)+(w5*w8)]+x3[(w3*w7)+(w6*w8)] = y$

Here, x1, x2, x3, and y are known entities. I have around 500 equations having the same characteristics. Hence, I reduced them and got the below mentioned form.

${(w1*w7)+(w4*w8)=k1}$
${(w2*w7)+(w5*w8)=k2}$
${(w3*w7)+(w6*w8)=k3}$

Here, I only know the values of k1, k2, and k3. I know this problem has a non-convex characteristic but, is there a way to identify the values of w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, and w8.

Moreover, I can see the above set of equations as matrix form (AX=B) too.

Where, A could 
\begin{bmatrix} 
w1 & w4 \\
w2 & w5  \\
w3 & w6
\end{bmatrix}
**X**
\begin{bmatrix}
w7  \\
w8   \\
\end{bmatrix}

**B**
\begin{bmatrix}
k1  \\
k2   \\
k3
\end{bmatrix}

Where I know B only.

I tried to initialize random values to matrix A to solve X. Unfortunately, I could not able to make an adaptation mechanism which updates the values of matrix A and leads to local minima.

I look forward to seeing the positive reply from the community.

Comment: What is to be minimized?

Comment: The cost function, say a min square error, something like (y-y')^2 with respect to weights (all w)